# Hover toolkit with actions

Tags: monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I'm trying to figure out how to configure the hover toolkit in monaco editor with clickable actions like in VS Code (see screenshot below) that execute another function. My app is react-based. I'd appreciate any ideas.

Example:

[image: vsc-hover-toolkit].

Dummy code:

```
const hoverProvider = monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider(mylang, {
      provideHover: (model, position) => {
          return {
            range: new monaco.Range(
              position.lineNumber,
              position.lineNumber,
              model.getWordAtPosition(position).startColumn,
              model.getWordAtPosition(position).endColumn,
            ),
            contents: [
              { supportHtml:true, value: `<>What html element here ?</>` },
            ],
          };
        }
      },
    });
```

I've tried rendering a component into a string using the ReactDOMServer, but it didn't work as well as other HTML elements, buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add HTML in the hover contents, but Markup text, which also supports links.

Create your contents array like this:

````js
contents: [
    { value: "```ts\nlet a: string\n```" },
    { value: "[Hello](http://www.microsoft.com)" },
],
````

In fact that `contents` array is defined as:

```
    export interface Hover {
        /**
         * The contents of this hover.
         */
        contents: IMarkdownString[];
        /**
         * The range to which this hover applies. When missing, the
         * editor will use the range at the current position or the
         * current position itself.
         */
        range?: IRange;
    }
```

Comment: I tried with something like `[Hello](javascript:alert('Hello World'))` and `<a href="javascript:alert('test')></a>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Alert will not work in VS Code, but see my update.

Comment: Apologies, I should've been more precise - the Monaco editor runs as a part of a JSX component. And I'm trying to replicate the VS Code buttons functionality from the hover toolkit (these from the screenshot, e.g. Quick Fix) so that it executes a function.